# Prevent mediascanner from scanning USB devices

Tags: boot, usb, media

Is there a way to prevent mediascanner from scanning usb disks? I don't want or need my 5TB external drive to be scanned for media every time I boot (or it's connected).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a file to the root directory on your USB drive called `.nomedia`

This will tell mediascanner to not scan the directory that it's in or any directories below it.